# How to change the scope of the function passed in to the eventClick property on a FullCalendar object?

Tags: javascript, scope, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar as a plugin for doing some stuff. I am initializing the calendar as instructed in the docs:

```
_initializeCalendar: function() {
        let me = this;
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: me._createEvents(me.releaseStore),
            eventClick: me._onEventClick
        });
    },
```

And I need to change the scope of the function passed in to the eventClick property, because my _onEventClick function will then use functions which are obviously not in the scope of the division where the click event happens. Here is the _onEventClick function:

```
_onEventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        console.log(scope);
        let modal = Ext.get('modal');
        let html = `
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">×</span>
                <h2>${calEvent.title}</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Name: ${calEvent.title}</p>
                <p>Release Date: ${calEvent.start}</p>
                <p>Team: ${calEvent.team}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        `;
        modal.setHTML(html);
        modal.setVisible(true);

        // closes modal when X close button is clicked
        $('.close').click(function() {
            let modal = Ext.get('modal');
            modal.setVisible(false);
        });
    }
```

So, is there any way to pass the global scope to the eventClick property of fullcalendar? Thank you.

Comment: Can you get the global scope from window?

Comment: It was actually as easy as just using bind. So when passing the function to the property it would be like this:

eventClick: me.onEventClick.bind(me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just using bind when passing the function to the object property.
So in code it would look like this:

```
clickEvent: me._onEventClick.bind(me)
```

Here "me" gets set to "this" in _initializeCalendar, so "this" has the global scope.